# Linq to Charts and Graphs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL express 2012 database. I have written several linq queries to bring back various interesting data just using Linqpad but I need a way to generate easy to see charts and graphs from this data.

I don't have any budget to buy any expensive licenses.  Is there anything free that I could use in either a console app or asp.net site to generate nice looking charts and graphs from my linq to sql queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For asp.net you could use the charts from the AjaxControllToolkit
Examples:

- [Line Chart](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/LineChart/LineChart.aspx)
- [Pie Chart](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PieChart/PieChart.aspx)
- [Bubble Chart](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/BubbleChart/BubbleChart.aspx)
- [Area Chart](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AreaChart/AreaChart.aspx)
- [Bar Chart](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/BarChart/BarChart.aspx)

Its free, easy to use and really looks nice to me.
Used it in many projects allready.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft released a chart control a while back that's free and works with both windows and ASP.NET.  Some info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489238%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It's probably included in the framework, or a standalone download for the older framework is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422).

Anyway, you have to convert your LINQ entities into the objects that the chart control expects, but it's not that hard to do.  Some examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235117/ASP-NET-Chart-Control).

Answer (score 3):

In case You are developing a web frontend, you could project your results into json and use http://d3js.org/ .